# codeigniter form send file null

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I tried send an image in  a form using codeigniter this way:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('noticia/inserir', 'id="form-pessoas"'); ?>

<label for="titulo">Título:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="titulo" value="<?php echo set_value('titulo'); ?>"/>
<div class="error"><?php echo form_error('resumo'); ?></div>

<label for="resumo">Resumo:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="resumo" value="<?php echo set_value('resumo'); ?>"/>
<div class="error"><?php echo form_error('resumo'); ?></div>

<label for="descricao">Descrição:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="descricao" value="<?php echo set_value('descricao'); ?>"/>
<div class="error"><?php echo form_error('descricao'); ?></div>

<label for="data">Data</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="data" value="<?php echo set_value('data'); ?>"/>
<div class="error"><?php echo form_error('data'); ?></div>

<label for="Foto">Foto:</label>
<input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('foto'); ?>"/>

<input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" />

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

But the input file send null.

My controller:

```
function inserir()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');


    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span>', '</span>');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('titulo', 'Titulo', 'required|max_length[60]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('resumo', 'Resumo', 'required|max_length[100]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descricao', 'Descrição', 'required|max_length[100]');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('data', 'Data', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->index();

    } else {

        $data['ds_titulo'] = $this->input->post('titulo');
        $data['ds_resumo'] = $this->input->post('resumo');
        $data['ds_noticia'] = $this->input->post('descricao');
        $data['ds_foto'] = $this->input->post('foto');
        //$data['data'] = $this->input->post('data');
        var_dump($this->input->post('foto'));exit;

        $this->upload($data);


        if ($this->model->inserir($data)) {
            redirect('noticia');
        } else {
            log_message('error', 'Erro ao inserir a noticia.');
        }
    }
}



  function upload($data){

    var_dump($data);exit;
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');


    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($data['foto']))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('cadastro-noticia', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        return true;


    }
}
```

Need to get the image file and upload then record the data in the database, but the problem starts right on sending data by form, anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var_dump($_FILES['foto']);exit;
```

And info You can not set file input value by anything..

```
<input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('foto'); ?>"/>
```

SO Here value attribute is of no use... :)

```
<input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" size="20" />
```